# Photoshop Document size changed in illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have document created in illustrator 3600 x 3600 pixel 300 PPI and then I opened with Photoshop to make it 1200 x 1200 pixel with same resolution 300.

I created back document in illustrator 1200 x 1200 pixel 300 PPI and placed the file I made 1200 pixel in Photoshop,However the file size become 288 x 288 pixel,

this is happening only if I save as , not happening when I m saving save for web

Thank you

Comment: Illustrator assumes a pixel ia 1/72th of an inch no matter what you say.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure why you are doing this. Couldn't you just export an image from Illustrator in the desired size?

Anyway, I think there is some confusion regarding "ppi". If the dimensions of your document are defined in pixels, you must be creating something for screen (not print) and then the resolution (ppi = pixels per inch) doesn't have any meaning. Resolution only matters when you are creating a design for print (or other physical products) with a physical size.

For example your 1200 x 1200 px image. By setting the resolution to 300 ppi you are indirectly setting the recommended physical size.

`physical size = pixel size / resolution`

`physical width = 1200 px / 300 ppi = 4 inch = 10,16 cm`

The only difference between a 1200 x 1200 px image at 72 ppi and a 1200 x 1200 px image at 300 ppi is the size they get by default when being placed in Photoshop/Illustrator/InDesign. They still contain the exact same pixel information.

In your case it seems you are placing a 300 ppi image (or ai?) in a 72 ppi Photoshop document:

`(72 ppi / 300 ppi) * 1200 px = 288 px`

So you should be able to just manually scale it to fit the document (when placing, not afterwards!) without loosing quality.

You could probably avoid it if you changed the resolution to 300 ppi in the Photoshop document before placing. But does it make sense in your case?

When you are "saving for web" you are creating a 72 ppi image which automatically fits your 72 ppi Photoshop document.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a few things going on that you need to keep in mind when working in Illustrator...

- Illustrator documents don’t have an inherent PPI value; they’re vector so don’t need it. The option you set when creating a new document only affects the resolution of raster *effects*, nothing more.
- Illustrator has no real concept of pixels. It works on physical measurements and for convenience always assumes that 1px = 1pt (1/72 inch). This has the consequence of everything in Illustrator being 72 PPI (they can be *rendered*  or exported at a higher resolution but everything is *measured* in the document as if they are 72 PPI)
- Placed artwork will be placed at the correct *physical* size. So a 300 x 300 pixel image saved at 300 PPI will be placed as a 1 x 1 inch image; resave the same image at 1 PPI (without changing the size in pixels) and it will be placed at 300 x 300 inches.

This is why a 300 PPI image is placed smaller than you would expect if you’re working in pixels and why this doesn’t happen if you “Save for Web” from Photoshop (Save for Web always automatically sets the PPI of the resulting file to 72 PPI).

It’s worth noting that if you’re working with pixel sizes in Illustrator (so I assume you’re working for screens) then there’s no reason to be setting you’re files to 300 PPI. If you’re not working for screens then don’t use pixel measurements in Illustrator.

With all that in mind....

- If you’re working in pixel sizes in Illustrator, always save placed artwork at 72 PPI at the correct pixel size.
- If you’re working in physical sizes, always save at the correct physical size (and set the PPI/pixel size to whatever you require).